# JavaScript Brackets in $('#nr[1]')

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, brackets

I have a problem maybe you can help me? input is name="name [1]" 
Is it possible to use:

```
$('#name[1]').val(myvariable);
```

Because the brackets from input name can not be removed, and with them that does not work. ;)

Sorry I wrote with google translate :)

Comment: Can you post an example of the `HTML`?

Comment: `$('#name')` will do anyway, because your IDs *should* be unique.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$('#name[1]')` would look for an element with an id of name and an attribute [1].  You can try this instead:

```
$('[name="name\\[1\\]"]').val(myvariable);
```

This will search for an element with a name = name[1].

FYI, You have to escape the brackets with 2 backslashes like that because you're actually escaping two things.  The double backslash "\" escapes to "\" in JavaScript. Then jQuery sees the "[" and escapes the bracket.

Answer (score 0):

If your input has the attribute `name` set to `name[1]`, then you can select it via;

```
$('input[name="name\\[1\\]"]').val(myvariable);
```

... per the [escaping rules](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) for jQuery selectors. Note the lack of the `#` in the selector. That's the [ID selector](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/). If your input has an *id* of `name[1]` (e.g. `<input id="name[1]" />`), use;

```
$('#name\\[1\\]').val(myvariable);
```

Comment: Not technically necessary to escape special characters if you wrap the attribute value in quotes, but still good to know how to do it and when you need to.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist: Whilst true, that behaviour isn't documented on the jQuery API, so it's possible (however unlikely) that that behaviour would change in the future.

Comment: Hm, I always thought it was documented in the API, but I just checked the page on selectors and you're right.

Answer (score 0):

You're using a # which is an ID selector. You can select your input using the following selector:

```
$('input[name="name[1]"]')
```

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery Selectors documentation have a explanation about this...

http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

> To use any of the meta-characters ( such as  !"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[]^`{|}~ ) as a literal part of a name, it must be escaped with with two backslashes: \. For example, an element with id="foo.bar", can use the selector $("#foo\.bar").

you can do...

```
$('#name\\[1\\]').val(myvariable); // if is in ID
$('input[name="name[1]"]').val(myvariable); // if is in Name
```